# Parametro por nome na consulta

Tags: banco-de-dados, laravel, select, laravel-eloquent

Tenho a seguinte consulta

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ip = 192.168.1.2
```

Gostaria de fazer uma consulta enviando parâmetro por nome usando `DB::raw()`

```
$dados = DB::raw("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ip = :ip", ["ip" => '192.168.1.2'])
```

É possível?

Tentei desse jeito mas não consegui

Quero fazer assim, porque caso tenha uma consulta que repita mais um vez o parâmetro eu não tenha que repetir variável

Comment: O que você realmente quer fazer??? não entendi ... só respondendo isso que perguntou dessa forma ai não ... !

Comment: Ao invés de usar `?` pelo parâmetro como algum nome. Exemplo: `WHERE id = ?` usar `WHERE id = :id`, em algumas consultas eu preciso repetir esse id

Comment: Entendi, mas, no `\DB::raw` não tem isso.

Comment: Etntendi! Beleza, valeu!